Does Romania retain theoretical ownership of the Patriot system they sent to Ukraine?
RFERL:

"We confirm that the Patriot system has arrived in Ukraine," Constantin Spinu, a spokesman for Romania's Defense Ministry, told RFE/RL on October 3, after the government in Bucharest last month passed a bill needed for the transfer of the system to Kyiv.
Under the bill, Romania grants Ukraine the right of free use of the system.

So, is this basically like a [free] lease? I.e. does Romania expect the system back when the war is over, or something like that?
BTW, another RFERL piece says something rather different:

Romania decided to donate one of its two operational Patriot systems - one of five such systems and other strategic air defence units pledged by NATO states to Kyiv - on condition that allies replace it with another Patriot system at a later date.
The draft law parliament approved states the replacement Patriot system from the United States should not cost more than Romania originally paid per unit, and that the costs will be covered from "non-refundable foreign sources".

So, besides the possibly wishful thinking or promises that they'd get another for free from the West, this other piece says that as far as Ukraine is concerned they own it now. OTOH this 2nd news piece is a month older, and so I'm not sure if the draft bill was changed/ammended in the meantime.

It doesn't seem to be mentioned in that article so it would be a guess on that issue. Why does who the owner is matter for this?

@JoeW: maybe there are more detailed sources about this in Romanian? After all, it says they passed a bill just for this.

I'd read "free use of the system" in that quote as "without restrictions" rather than "without cost" (although it may also be without cost to Ukraine).

I think what you are looking for is unknowable at this point in time, It could be if the Patriot system survives the conflict it is returned to them, it also could be that if it is destroyed or damaged beyond repair during the conflict it is replaced by other sources. One of the big concerns about equipment like this is that Russia is going to attempt to target and destroy it as it is a threat to their operations.

@JoeW: I'm not asking any of that. I'm just asking if the Romanian law or agreement with Ukraine says they'd have to give it back under some circumstances.

The article you quoted seems pretty clear that they want a replacement in some form or other and it is likely written with the understanding that the one they are sending will become destroyed or damaged beyond repair. It should be noted that they are reported to cost 1.1 billion per system which is why they want something for it.

@JoeW Afaik it might be a borrow. Quite a risky one - there is no warranty if Ukraine will exist at the end of the war and it will have both the will and the capability to give back anything.

Unless Romania said so, who can know what they expect? Maybe they aren't sure either.

"does Romania expect the system back when the war is over" If they do, surely not in the condition it was sent. It will at the very least be somewhat degraded. And Romania is probably less interested in exactly this system, just in that their number of systems doesn't decrease too much. Maybe they can get additional ones from somewhere else.

Are you really Asking whether Romania retains ownership, or whether Romania retains licensing control over use?
Either way are you suggesting the two are the same, is that legally or in practical terms?
At the end of the day, why would anyone care, unless this is really about how Ukraine is allowed to use the Romanian equipment?

The agreement signed with Ukraine in July, published in English by the latter, says it's a donation:

Romania will donate to Ukraine a PATRIOT system, in accordance with the decision of the National Supreme Defence Council of Romania on 20 June 2024.
[...] Signed in Washington D.C., on 11 July 2024, in two original copies, in the English, Ukrainian and Romanian languages. In case of any discrepancy, the text in English will prevail.

So, I think this how Ukraine sees it, although more details from the Romanian documents would be welcome.

It would help if you can highlight if Romania itself has complete ownership in the first place. Most of these systems are sold by the US with strict end user clauses that can even prevent Romania from selling (or giving away) these systems to another country without the explicit consent of the US.
